# showing a dialog box based on a if/else statement

Tags: java, android

I have a very simple method where if the number of click counts equal 4, 8, 12 then output relevant messages, else for every 4th number output a general message. This is all displayed within a dialog but what I notice is the else statement appears for every increase of the click count by one. I am not sure why that is?

What I also don't get is every time the dialog box appears, it takes more attempts to dismiss it. For example when it opens first time I click on the ok button once and it closes. When it opens the second time it takes 2 clicks of ok to close it. £ times equals 3 times and etc.

```
        selectAnotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getClickCountInt++;

                if (getClickCountInt == 4){
                    ShowRewardDialog("You are rewarded with a the yellow smiley face in the homepage");
                } else if (getClickCountInt == 8) {
                    ShowRewardDialog("You are rewarded with a the green smiley face in the homepage");
                 } else if (getClickCountInt == 12) {
                    ShowRewardDialog("You are rewarded with a the red smiley face in the homepage");
                 } else {
                    for(int i = 0; i <= getClickCountInt; i+=4) {
                    ShowRewardDialog("You are rewarded with a video\"");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

 private void ShowRewardDialog(String message) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Content.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

        SpannableString title = new SpannableString("YOU GAINED A REWARD");

        title.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Content.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.purple))
                , 0, title.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
        dialog.setTitle(title);

        text.setText(message);

        Button dialogButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_OK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason for taking more attempts is for example 9 it shows a new dialog  box on the same place three times which is on 0,4 and 8 as the for loop functions so either use `break;` in your loop so only one dialog box appears or use a boolean logic or something which checks for an already visible dialog box before showing a new one.

Comment: you fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that you are opening multiple windows in the same place, caused by this loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= getClickCountInt; i+=4) {
    ShowRewardDialog("You are rewarded with a video\"");
}
```

Let's say getClickCountInt is 10.

- i starts at 0. 0 is less than or equal to 10. It shows the reward dialog.
- i becomes 4. 4 is less than or equal to 10. It shows the reward dialog.
- i becomes 8. 8 is less than or equal to 10. It shows the reward dialog.
- i becomes 12. 12 is bigger than 10. It stops the loop, and the reward dialog is not shown.

So, you now have 3 reward dialogs, perfectly overlapping. When you press the close button once, it closes the first one--but there's still 2 more right behind it. Even though you closed one, it looks like nothing happened.

The easiest way to solve this is to get rid of the for loop. Instead, use the mod operation to determine if getClickCountInt is a multiple of four.

The mod symbol performs division, and returns the remainder.

For example, lets say you have 10 divided by four. You can fit four into 10 two times, and you will have  2 left over. A number is a multiple of another if the remainder is 0.

For example four goes into twelve 3 times, with nothing left over. So, 12 is a multiple of four!

The code to do this is easier than it sounds. Simply replace the for loop with this!

```
if(getClickCountInt % 4 == 0){
    ShowRewardDialog("You are rewarded with a video\"");
}
```